# What is the difference for x.509 certificate serial number format in brackets and not in brackets.

Tags: ssl, certificate, x509

I have generated a certificate that has the serial number in such a format
*0eaa20f53cacdcaa40fbde51ab50c7d1*

I have also seen a certificate with this format. I would like to generate one like this.
*10978342379280287625 (0x985ae83a6b9e477f)*

How can I do this? Whats the difference?

Comment: The serial number is an [ASN.1 binary integer up to 20 octets](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3280.txt), not in any of these formats. You're only looking at different ways of *printing* it.

Comment: are you asking in program or in general?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An [X.509 Serial Number](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.1.2.2) is an integer whose value can be represented in 20 bytes ("or less", because Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER) say you omit any unnecessary leading 0x00 bytes (it's necessary if it changes from a negative to positive number, or if it's the number 0).

> 10978342379280287625 (0x985ae83a6b9e477f)

If you go to a website that does big number conversions, such as http://www.mobilefish.com/services/big_number/big_number.php you'll see that
`985ae83a6b9e477f (hex)` is equal to `10978342379280287615 (decimal)`.

The DER encoded value of this number is `02 09 00 98 5a e8 3a 6b 9e 47 7f`

> 0eaa20f53cacdcaa40fbde51ab50c7d1

This number (DER `02 10 0e aa 20 f5 3c ac dc aa 40 fb de 51 ab 50 c7 d1`) is equivalent to the decimal value `19492550873724953657229484824238016465`.

Assuming the same software displayed both renderings, like OpenSSL, the difference in whether or not it displays in both decimal and hex likely has to do with the length of the serial number.  For OpenSSL the cutoff is 8 content (non-0x00) bytes: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/c4a60150914fc260c3fc2854e13372c870bdde76/crypto/x509/t_x509.c#L88

Since `0x985ae83a6b9e477f` fits into an `unsigned long`, OpenSSL prints it as a decimal value for user convenience.